# Can you add 2 global variables work inside a function while inside a while loop?

Tags: python, function, loops, global-variables

I am trying to build a function with a loop inside.

```
import time
#example

def infiniteloop2():
  while True:
    print("hi")
    time.sleep(1)  
  
infiniteloop2()
```

One thing I encountered was errors in adding 2 global variables.

```
import time
x=7
y=3
#example

def infiniteloop2():
  while True:
    print("hi")
    x=x+y
    time.sleep(1)  
    
infiniteloop2()
```

This code gives me an error. What am I missing?

Also, my question was closed due to an apparent duplicate. There is a difference because there is a loop, and instead of `print` functions there is an `+` operator. unless you are the person who is reviewing this, you can ignore this part.

Comment: what error are you getting? When tried your code in my editor I don't get any.

Comment: oops! wrong code! The right code is 2 variables. I tried x=x+y inside the loop and it gave an error.

Comment: can you modify your code in question so that we can know what it looks like?

Comment: both are global variables

Comment: i would recommend editing your question with the code you have. Then we can look into it.

Comment: What you are missing in your code is ```global x, y```. To use ```global variables``` in ```local scope``` of a function, you need to tell computer that the variable you are trying to manipulate is a ```global```. So, add ```global x, y``` before referencing ```x``` and ```y```.

Comment: With `x = ...`, `x` is no longer a global variable, but a local variable that's not yet initialized the first time you execute `x = x + y`.

Comment: I have no idea what you’re trying to say with your latest edit…

Comment: @Andrew The linked duplicate answers your question, if you think it doesn't read it more carefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your code and I didn't get any errors. Could you specify what error you get?

Edit: You need to add global before adding them.
Edit 2: If you want to change a global variable add global keyword inside the function. Hope this helps.

```
import time
x=7
y=3
#example

def infiniteloop2():
  while True:
    global x
    x=x+y
    print("hi")
    print(x+y)
    time.sleep(1)  
    
infiniteloop2()
```

Comment: oops! wrong code! The right code is 2 variables. I tried x=x+y inside the loop and it gave an error.